# Concatenate variable with dot notation

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, concatenation

```
request(`http://127.0.0.1:3000`)
                .post(`${this.apiVersion}${apiEndpoint})
                .set('Accept', acceptType)
                .set('Content-Type', contentType)
                .set('Authorization', authorization)
```

I have above request of mocha test. I want to use variable requestMethod for http request (post, get, put).

```
.post(`${this.apiVersion}${apiEndpoint})
```

like in above code i want use requestMethod variable instead of using post to make it configurable. How can i concatenate dot notation with variable ? 
I have tried it with following code but it didn't work.

```
'.'+requestMethod+'('+ this.apiVersion + apiEndpoint +')'
```

Comment: What is `request`? Please post the `require` or `import` statement as well.

Comment: request is of supertest library. 
const request = require('supertest');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, you can access the properties (and, weirdly, methods) as indexes of an array of the object. So, if you do:

```
request(`http://127.0.0.1:3000`)[requestMethod](`${this.apiVersion}${apiEndpoint}`)
            .set('Accept', acceptType)
            .set('Content-Type', contentType)
            .set('Authorization', authorization))
```

It should work.